# What does the $encoding parameter of htmlspecialchars() do?

Tags: php, string, htmlspecialchars

I am working with the `htmlspecialchars()` function in PHP which takes an optional third parameter `$encoding`.

According to the [official documentation of `htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), `$encoding` is...

> An optional argument defining the encoding used when converting characters.

Now, I don't understand which encoding is the documentation talking about here. **Does `$encoding` specify the encoding of the string that's input to `htmlspecialchars()` or the encoding of the string that's returned by the function?**

And, as far as I see it, I don't think that there's a point of specifying the encoding. Can anyone please also give me an example of where would specifying the encoding make sense?

Comment: I think it specifies both the input and output of the function. You wouldn't want the function to change it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware then what's the point of specifying it? Can you please give me an example to help me understand it better?

Comment: Imagine you're reading a CSV file encoded in `ISO-8859-1`, but your PHP script default_charset configuration option is set to `UTF-8`, and you want to process the CSV file in it's original encoding. In that case it would be handy if you can do that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I still don't understand the purpose of `$encoding` in `htmlspecialchars()`. Upon inspecting all the possible charsets that could be provided in `$encoding`, they all have the same mapping for the characters that `htmlspecialchars()` changes. So, what's the point of specifying the encoding?

Comment: There are encodings that use a single byte to encode all their characters and there are so-called _"multibyte character encoding schemes"_ that use multiple bytes. If `htmlspecialchars()` thinks it's dealing with individual bytes for each character, but in reality it needs to look at multiple bytes, things can go very wrong.

Comment: If you are just looking for an example of that function behaving differently depending on that parameter, see https://3v4l.org/fQYWL#v8.1.18

Comment: I think the key point you're missing is that, unlike other languages (Java or JavaScript come to my mind), strings in PHP are binary data. PHP just sees a stream of bytes. Text manipulation functions either use a hard-coded encoding (often ISO-8859-1) if they're very old, or ask for it (defaulting to some configurable encoding). And not all encodings are backward compatible with US-ASCII.

Comment: Said that... You kind of have a point with this specific function. The encoding list is limited, all the them appear to be supersets of UTF-8 and the few entities being converted have the same encoding. Main use here is to avoid mangling data when it contains non-ASCII characters, e.g. https://3v4l.org/IEXeU#v8.1.18

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález don't you feel that the official documentation on php.net for `htmlspecialchars()` could be improved to describe `htmlspecialchars()` in a better way? I feel that it could explain the exact purpose of `$encoding`. IMO, I think that `$encoding` only has to do with how invalid characters are dealt.

Comment: What do you mean with invalid characters? This is like a currency exchange convertor, you don't provide the currency to deal with invalid numbers, you do it to know what the numbers mean. I'm just saying that it isn't obvious in which edge cases a _wrong_ encoding can produce incorrect output, but the meaning of the encoding parameter itself is perfectly clear. Also, if explained here, it'd had to be explained in 200 other functions.